# Applications worked on Windows XP but not ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

Please help me out. I have replaced XP with Ubuntu 14.04 and the free stand alone applications that used to work on XP will not install on Ubuntu. What can i do to get the applications installed and working. The error received says something to the likes of unable to Archive..........

Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu and Windows are two different system, so not all applications that work on Windows will work on Ubuntu. There is an emulator (Wine), but it's not compatible with all software. What's the name of the application you're trying to run?

Comment: ISOTOUSB and MAGICISO.

Comment: Okay, you can easily write ISO to USB in Ubuntu with `dd`, I'll explain it later in an answer. What do you need MagicISO for?

Comment: Since i'm new to Ubuntu since last night i thought that i'd need to install magiciso as i did with microsoft to burn iso images. thanks for the headsup. would you also happen to know where i can find the Kali image as its part of my practical. The iso image i downloaded was only 8mb and only PDF files were inside it.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

Programs for Windows do not work on Linux (except if you use wine).

Some software is available for multiple platforms. For example, Libreoffice and Firefox are available for Windows and Linux.

Some software is available only for Windows. The good news is that for most Windows only software there is an "equivalent" on Linux. Search the Software Center and the internet to find the closest equivalent to the software you're trying to substitute.

Lastly, if you really need a windows program with no real equivalent for linux, you can try installing "wine" and try installing it on linux. Not all software will work but many will.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback ...

Answer (score 1):

Windows and Ubuntu are two different systems. Therefore you can't just run Windows applications on Ubuntu and vice versa.

There is an emulator for Windows applications on Ubuntu (called Wine), but as you said in the comments you only want to use those programs to write an ISO to USB or CD, so I'll just explain how to do that using Ubuntu's own tools.

---

### ISO to USB

You can write an ISO to USB using `dd`.

**Note:** by using `dd` you'll destroy all data on your destination drive. Also be sure to specify the right destination drive, because if you specify the wrong destination drive all data will be gone and most of it wil be unrestorable.

1. Open a terminal
2. Execute the following command:

   ```
   sudo dd if=/path/to/image.iso of=/dev/sdb
   ```

   Replace `/path/to/image.iso` by the path to the ISO file you want to write and `/dev/sdb` by the device path of the (USB) drive you want to write the ISO file to.

   This command will just write the contents of the ISO file bit for bit to the destination drive, including the MBR (if there's one) and the whole partition layout, so it'll be bootable.

You can find the device path of your USB drive this way:

1. Open a terminal
2. Execute the following command:

   ```
   lsblk
   ```
3. You'll see a list of device paths. You can use the size to determine which one is your USB drive, or you can run the command before you insert the USB drive and after you insert the USB drive, to see what has changed.

   **Note:** in this case you'll not need the partitions (`/dev/sda1` is partition 1, `/dev/sda2` is partition 2 etc), but the drive itself (`/dev/sda`).

---

### ISO to CD

To write an ISO to disc you can simply use Ubuntu's file manager.

1. Open your file manager
2. Browse for the ISO file
3. Right click on the ISO file and click on `Write to Disc...`
4. Follow the on-screen instructions

---

### Kali ISO

You can find a link to the Kali ISO [here](http://www.kali.org/downloads/).

Comment: Is it necessary to run an antivirus and firewall on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Not really. You could install antivirus if you're mailing files to people using Windows for example, but not necessary. A firewall is not necessary too because a computer is usually behind your router's (or ISP's) firewall.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a Windows environment to use Windows only programs you also have the option to install ubuntu parallel to Windows or install Windows as a guest system within Ubuntu (use https://www.virtualbox.org/) or install Ubuntu as a guest system witin Windows (use https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide). I asume you had your reasons for migrating to Ubuntu and there are really a lot of useful substitutes for Windows programs within the Ubuntu ecosystem. And they are getting better and better.

Comment: Thanks for the link to virtual box. I found that Windows Virtual PC is just a nightmare to work on and does not have all the functionality described by users who use Virtualbox ..